# fetch and handleFetch's event parameter - sveltejs/kit

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, svelte, sveltekit

As per my observations, there are three functions (handle(), handleFetch(), and handleError()) designed to handle fetch requests. Each of these functions accepts an event parameter, which includes a `route.id`. However, I've noticed that the handleFetch() function, while including the `route.id` parameter, seems to display the route from where the fetch() is called rather than the specific endpoint mentioned in fetch().

for example:

calling fetch from `+page.server.js` from the url `http://localhost:5173/admin/users/123`

```
export const load = async ({ fetch, params }) => {
  const id = params.id;
  const response = await fetch(`/api/users/${id}`);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};
```

handling fetch from the three functions in `+hooks.server.ts`:

```
export const handle: Handle = ({ event, }) => {
  console.log(event.route.id); // expected result: api/users/[id]
  // output result: api/users/[id]
};

export const handleFetch: HandleFetch = ({ event }) => {
  console.log(event.route.id); // expected result: api/users/[id]
  // output result: admin/users/123 --> UGH!!!!
};

export const handleError = ({ event }) => {
  console.log(event.route.id); api/users/[id]
  // output result: api/users/[id]
};
```

Thank you for your attention to this matter, and I appreciate any insights or guidance you can provide to resolve this discrepancy.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I think this works as intended, `handleFetch` wraps every fetch made on the server itself and this includes calls to third party sources (which do not have a route.id).  It's purpose is to reroute or add extra information to these requests.  I would say it is poorly documented though.

Comment: also: `route.id` gives you the _current route_, which in the case of handleFetch is where the fetch originates, and for handle and handleError is where you are (or try to be at least)

Comment: @StephaneVanraes While I understand that handleFetch() wraps every fetch made on the server. My concern stems from the fact that the event.route.id parameter in handleFetch() seems to include an unexpected result (admin/users/123) which does not align with the behavior of the event.route.id parameters in the handle() and handleError() functions. The latter two functions correctly provide the route of the API being called.

Comment: @StephaneVanraes Given that the event parameter for all three functions (handle(), handleFetch(), and handleError()) has the same type (RequestEvent), it seems puzzling why the event.route.id value would differ between handleFetch() and the other two functions.

Comment: That is purely a misunderstanding `handle` returns the route you currently are on and are trying to render, `handleError` returns the route you currently are on and where an error occured, `handleFetch` is returning the route you currently are on.
If you do a fetch from one of your own api's within the same sequence `handleFetch` will be on the route you *are* and `handle` will be the route it tries to render (aka the route you request)

Comment: @StephaneVanraes ah okay i got your points, you're right, I've tested the scenarios you suggested with different cases, that's exactly what i got. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation

Comment: @ilyassmabrouk I added it as an answer in case others come across the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is the question of *"where"* and *"when"* these functions run, and what `event.route.id` actually is.

In all three cases, the `route.id` is the current location the function is executed.

For both `handle` and `handleError` this is *the page or endpoint being rendered*, while for `handleFetch` this is *the page doing the request*.

A simple example might show it more.

```js
// /routes/+page.server.js
export const load = async ({ fetch }) => {
  console.log('in page.server');
  const res = await fetch('/api').then((res) => res.json());
  return {
    res
  };
};
```

```js
// /routes/api/+server.js
import { json } from '@sveltejs/kit';
export const GET = async () => {
  console.log('in api');
  return json({ status: 'ok' });
};
```

```js
// /hooks.server.js
export const handle = async ({ event, resolve }) => {
    console.log('in handle', event.route.id);
    return await resolve(event);
};

export const handleFetch = ({ event, request, fetch }) => {
  console.log('in fetch', event.route.id);
  return fetch(request);
};
```

Here we have a very simple setup of just a page that does a request to an internal api during load.

When loading the page we get the following output in the console
| output | commentary |
|---|---|
|in handle / | trying to render the root |
|in page.server | page load function |
|in fetch / | still on the root, doing a fetch |
|in handle /api | trying to render the api call |
|in api | in the api GET |